# The father has the obligation of chinuch until what age

Tags: children-parenting, chinuch-education, age

Until what age is the obligation on the father to train his children to do Mitzvot?
I see contradictory sources please clarify, or bring more accepted sources

**No limit**.    http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Chinuch#Until_When.3F
There was a video of the Rebbe by dollars where he says until 120

**Until bar/bat mitzah**. 
 A Parent's Guide to Teaching Children Mitzvot: A Halakhic Guide By Shmuel Singer page [150](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nIFh.jpg)
He also brings:
Shulchan Arukh Even HaEzer [178.21](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.178.21)
Mishnah Berurah [225.7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.225.7)

Comment: Sounds like you have sources already. Please [edit] the question to clarify what it is you seek.

Comment: I don't see a contradiction.

Comment: @Heshy people with great minds can understand to opposite things at once, but maybe you can explain it for simple people like me

Comment: "Although the primary purpose of Chinuch is to train children when they are young so that they continue to perform the Mitzvot during adulthood, the parents' obligations does not end when a child reaches bar or bat mitzvah."  This is a quote from your link.  They acknowledge that the primary mitzvah is until 12/13.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what the Rebbe intended, but the Mishnah Berurah 225 [s.k. 7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.225.7) you brought writes regarding the bracha the father says when his son turns 13:

> ‏ (ז) שפטרני מענשו וכו' - פי' דעד עכשיו נענש האב כשחטא הבן בשביל שלא חנכו למצות התורה ועכשיו שנעשה איש מחוייב הוא להתחזק בעצמו למצות הש"י. ודע **דאע"פ ששוב אין עליו ענין חינוך מ"מ יש על האב מצות הוכחה** כשרואה שאינו מתנהג כשורה וכשאינו מוחה בידו נענש עליו דלא גרע משאר ישראל וכידוע מה שאחז"ל כל מי שיש לו למחות באנשי ביתו ואינו מוחה נתפס בעון אנשי ביתו. וכל מי שיש לו למחות באנשי עירו ואינו מוחה וכו': ‏
>
> Who exempted me - Meaning, until now (before 13) a father was punished when his son sins, since he didn't properly mechanech (educate) his son to follow the mitzvos of the Torah. Now that the child is a man, he (himself) is obligated to strengthen his commitment to Hashem's mitzvos. But know, that **even though the father no longer has an obligation of chinuch, still, the father is obligated to rebuke his son** when he sees him not acting properly. Further, when he doesn't rebuke his son, the father is punished, as he is no worse than anyone else (who is able to rebuke and fails to do so). For it is known what Chazal say, that anyone who can rebuke his household and fails to do so,  gets the punishment of his household. And anyone who fails to rebuke his townspeople...etc.

So the formal enactment of chinuch designed by Chazal is until 13, but a father is forever responsible for the spiritual well-being of his son, presumably because he is still an authority figure to the son.