# Bar Mitzva Blessing

Tags: chinuch-education, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

When a father says for his son ברוך שפטרני מעונשו של זה after his son read from the Torah-roll, he is according to some opinions, not only freeing himself from the punishment of his son's transgressions, but he is also "stopping" the punishment, if he was negligent and did not teach Torah to his child. This appears for example in Shaarei Ephraim, Schaar 4, Number 26. Does this mean that the obligation of teaching Torah lasts until the children become Bat/Bar Mitzvah?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The father has the obligation of chinuch until what age](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90503/the-father-has-the-obligation-of-chinuch-until-what-age). Your title makes it sound like a different question but, your question is not about the bracha but what the other question is asking

Comment: Btw, here are the halachos: Rambam Talmud Torah 1:1, Shulchan Aruch YD 245:1

Comment: thanks rabbi Kari